# Difficulty in building a self-organized network in NetLogo

Tags: network-programming, netlogo

I'm new to netlogo and I'm trying to build a network where nodes have a random number that changes with each tick, and connect randomly to other nodes. Once the connection is established I need that: if the number between the two nodes is the same then the link crystallizes and changes color, otherwise it is deleted for that tick, the procedure is repeated until all nodes have the same random value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not understanding one thing: when two turtles (the nodes) have the same number and happen to link to each other, do you want them to stop changing number?
I ask because... [1] If that's the case, then it will be unlikely that all turtles end up having the same value: it will be enough for just two links to form between two couples of turtles having two different values, that those four turtles will stop changing values and these will never converge.
[2] On the contrary, if that's not the case, turtles will just keep changing values so these will never converge either.
What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Matteo your point is correct! Each node once it connects to another with the same value stops changing it. The low probability that all nodes have the same value at the same time, just changing few parameters, is just what I would like to test (maybe it won't be what I expect but I would like to try it). In fact, the next step would be to make the nodes assume a particular spatial arrangement depending on how long they take to become homogeneous. The basic idea is to see how simple elements, which come together at random, with only some constraint, can give rise to something complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the clarification in the comments...

The thing you mentioned can be done in a fairly simple way, so hopefully you can use the explanation and keywords below to browse the NetLogo Manual (and in particular the NetLogo Dictionary) and become fully familiar with what is going on.

First, let's setup a few things

```
globals [
; You'll probably want to declare these two variables directly
; in the Interface with a slider or something, but here I'll
; set them up from within the Code section.

 number-of-turtles
 level-of-randomness 
]

turtles-own [
 my-number
 connected?
]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  set-globals
  
  create-turtles number-of-turtles [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set connected? false
  ]
end


to set-globals
  set number-of-turtles 500
  set level-of-randomness 1000
end
```

So far you have a number of turtles scattered in their environment, a couple of global variables that everyone can access, and a couple of variables belonging to each turtle to keep track of their state.

Based word for word on what you described, you could go on as:

```
to go.v1
; This first block of commands below is to get rid of the links that
; emerged in the previous iteration of 'go.v1', but that
; you don't want to keep because they link turtles with
; different 'my-number'. You will also need to include the
; stop condition that best suits you.
  ask links with [color != green] [
   die
  ]

; Insert here a stop condition.

  ask turtles with [connected? = false] [
   set my-number random level-of-randomness
  ]

; The 'let' command creates a local variable.
  ask turtles [
   let target one-of other turtles
   create-link-with target

; The statement below containing "[who] ..." is how you need to
; call a link: 'who' is a built-in turtle-own variable reporting
; the ID number of the turtle, and to report a link you will need
; to give it the two IDs of the two turtles being connected.

   if (my-number = [my-number] of target) [
     ask link ([who] of self) ([who] of target) [
       set color green
      ]
     if (connected? = false) [
       set connected? true 
      ]
     if ([connected?] of target = false) [
       ask target [
         set connected? true
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

The code above does what you said: each turtle always creates the link with another turtle, then the condition is tested, and based on that condition (the result of which is stored as the link's color: only the good links become `green`) the link is kept or eliminated at the beginning of the following iteration of `go.v1`.

However, although you may have reasons to do it in the way above, you might just be happy with an alternative which requires less computation:

```
to go.v2
  ; Insert here a stop condition.
  
  ask turtles with [connected? = false] [
   set my-number random level-of-randomness
  ]

  ask turtles [
   let target one-of other turtles
    
   if (my-number = [my-number] of target) [
     create-link-with target [
       set color green
       ask both-ends [
         if (connected? = false) [
           set connected? true
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

This way, turtles evaluate the potential companion before creating any link, and they only proceed to create it if `my-number` is the same.
That way, there is no need to create and then eliminate all the unwanted links (and the `my-number` condition had to be tested anyway even in `go.v1`).

Comment: Thank you so much Matteo! The code, with the other conditions added, works perfectly for my intent.